# SQL Server : SUM DISTINCT GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sapb1

I'm currently creating a query to sum the code below

```
select distinct
    opch.docentry as 'AP Invoice #',
    pch1.linenum as 'AP Invoice Line #',
    pch1.itemcode as 'Item Code',
    pch1.dscription as 'Item Name',
    pch1.freetxt as 'Free Text',
    pch1.priceafvat as 'Gross Price',
    pch1.quantity as 'Quantity',
    pch1.gtotal as 'Gross Total'
from 
    opch
inner join 
    pch1 on opch.docentry = pch1.docentry
inner join 
    opdn on opdn.docentry = pch1.basedocnum
inner join 
    pdn1 on opdn.docentry = pdn1.docentry
inner join 
    opor on opor.docentry = pdn1.basedocnum
inner join 
    por1 on opor.docentry = por1.docentry
where 
    pch1.u_budgetno = '57'
    and opch.canceled = 'N'
    and opdn.docstatus = 'C'
    and opdn.canceled = 'N'
    and opor.docstatus = 'C'
    and opor.canceled = 'N'
order by 
    opch.docentry
```

This is the sum statement I've tried

```
select 
    opch.docentry,
    sum(pch1.gtotal)
from
    opch
inner join 
    pch1 on opch.docentry = pch1.docentry
inner join 
    opdn on opdn.docentry = pch1.basedocnum
inner join 
    pdn1 on opdn.docentry = pdn1.docentry
inner join 
    opor on opor.docentry = pdn1.basedocnum
inner join  
    por1 on opor.docentry = por1.docentry
where 
    pch1.u_budgetno = '57'
    and opch.canceled = 'N'
    and opdn.docstatus = 'C'
    and opdn.canceled = 'N'
    and opor.docstatus = 'C'
    and opor.canceled = 'N'
group by 
    opch.docentry, opdn.docstatus
```

It however doesn't return the correct amount as it duplicates some answers based on the connected tables.

Requesting assistance on what I'm doing wrong.

*Update
This is the result from the select distinct query
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqjeO.png)

I'm aiming for the sum query to sum the results from the pch1.gtotal column

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and the output you expect to obtain from that data would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: No one can answer your question without seeing the issue with sample data, please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Usually there's a column called "baseentry" that links to subsequent document lines (you're using basedocnum), and the join condition must include the "basetype" as documents can be based on different document types.

Comment: Remove ` opdn.docstatus` from the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the join you are doing between the invoice and the delivery note. You are not joining the line so it multiplies the results. The correct join is done using BaseEntry, BaseLine and BaseType. The same applies to the join with the purchase order.

```
    select 
        opch.docentry,
        sum(pch1.gtotal)
    from
        opch
    inner join 
        pch1 on opch.docentry = pch1.docentry
    inner join 
        pdn1 on pdn1.docentry = pch1.baseentry and pdn1.linenum = pch1.baseline and  pdn1.objtype = pch1.basetype
    inner join 
        opdn on opdn.docentry = pdn1.docentry
    inner join 
        por1 on por1.docentry = pdn1.baseentry and por1.linenum = pdn1.baseline and por1.objtype = pdn1.basetype 
    inner join  
        opor on opor.docentry = por1.docentry
    where 
        pch1.u_budgetno = '57'
        and opch.canceled = 'N'
        and opdn.docstatus = 'C'
        and opdn.canceled = 'N'
        and opor.docstatus = 'C'
        and opor.canceled = 'N'
    group by 
        opch.docentry
```